# jQuery: Get last clicked element.id

Tags: jquery, menu, element

I need your help. I want to create a little menu with effects slideUp and slideDown.
I've found a solution, but i want to ask you if there is a "cleaner" and better solution.

Here's my Code:

```
var menu_id = "";
$('.menu li a').click(function(){
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    if(menu_id != ""){
        $('#frame-' + menu_id).slideUp();
    }
    if(currentId != menu_id){
        $('#frame-' + currentId).slideDown();
        menu_id = currentId;
    }
    else{
        menu_id = "blank"
    }
});
```

Regards
Dario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the post by sp00m try this

```
$(".menu li a").click(function() {
   var frame = $('#frame-' +  this.id);
   if ($(frame).is(":visible")) {
       $(frame).slideUp();
   }
   else{
       if($("[id^='frame-']:visible").length == 0)
       {
           $(frame).slideDown();
       }
       else if($("[id^='frame-']:visible").length == 1)
       {
           $("[id^='frame-']:visible").slideUp(function(){
               $(frame).slideDown();
           });
       }                   
   }
});
```

Comment: Perfect, this works. I only puted an else-query else{ $(frame).slideUp(); }, cause without this query, when i click the visible element again, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you just explain this source: $("[id^='frame-']") ? Do you get the current active frame?

Comment: this "^=" is a CSS selector meaning get all elements with attribute x starting with n. In your context, this selector get all the elements with id starting with "frame-".

Comment: So you slide every element except the current selected element up, and slide then the current selected down?

Comment: Dammit, i just added a new menupoint. Now it just slides down and up again.

Comment: Yup, well the jQuery ".not" function is used to prevent the current element to slide up.

Comment: No solution for more than 2 frames? I don't get it, why he slides the current one up if there are more then 2 frames.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking into it right now, I'm at work so I can't reply very fast.

Comment: Modified the code should work now...I take that there's only one frame opened at a time if not just add a "else" after the "if else".

Answer (score 2):

This should work too:

```
$(".menu li a").click(function() {
    var frame = $('#frame-' +  this.id);
    if (!$(frame).is(":visible")) {
        $("[id^='frame-']").slideUp();
        $(frame).slideDown();
    } else {
        $(frame).slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: @user1515190 I edited to match your needs. I'm not sure it's possible to wait until an animation is finished. At least, I don't know how to do ;)

Comment: Put the `slideDown()` function in the callback of the `slideUp()` function

Comment: $("[id^='frame-']").slideUp(function(){ $(frame).slideDown(); }); Something like that, right? But this doesn't work.